# Migrate command not transforming not creating table in database. Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql, migration

I created a model and migrated the changes to database and inserted some values in it. But at one point I accidentally deleted that table from database using pgAdmin 4 not from django I was trying to empty the table but accidentally deleted it. The model is still in django and I decided to migrate changes again so that that I could my table back in database. After running migrate it says that no migrations to apply but when I look in the database the table is not there.

I tried creating different models in the same app and tried migrating them they migrated but the model with the name same as model that I deleted is not migrating to the database.

I have deleted all the migrations and it still not taking it.

I think it is still somewhere in the django system from where it should be deleted or something.

Any help how can I get that same name model migrated to the database.

Comment: There is a table called django_migrations. Find the migration file name that you want re-migrated, and delete that row out of the table. Then you can re-run the migrate command line. Keep in mind, depending on how far behind that table migration was, you may run into dependency issues. You'll need to work through these yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Follow 4 below steps:

1. Delete the rows related to your app from django_migrations table in your database:

```
DELETE FROM django_migrations WHERE app='<app_name>';
```

---

2. Go to your app folder and delete migration folder.

---

3. Make migration:

```
py manage.py makemigrations <app_name>
```

---

4. And then migrate:

```
py manage.py migrate <app_name>
```